# Error on large data in FluentMigrator Execute(string template, params object[] args);

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, fluent-migrator

I have a `sql` script to migrate data from old table to new one with `FluentMigrator` execute method.

This is my script:

```
                INSERT INTO [Demo].[C]([key], [value], [tempID]) SELECT [name], [value], [userID] FROM [Demo].[A]
                INSERT INTO [Demo].[B]([parentID], [propertyID]) SELECT [tempID], [id] FROM [Demo].[C] WHERE [tempID] IS NOT NULL
                UPDATE [Demo].[C] SET [tempID] = NULL
```

The `userProperty` table has about 11 million rows and in:

- first step, I have to insert to some column in `C` table.(11 million rows)
- step two,  I have to inserting data from C table to B table.(11 million rows)
- step three, I should update C table (11 million rows)

Totally 11 million rows, but I getting this error:

> The error was The transaction log for database 'test' is full
>   due to 'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION'.

I want to find the fastest way to doing because this is `one time running` script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transaction log file is full and there is no left disk space for it to grow (if auto-grow option is specified).

Execute the query below to get more details about your transaction log file settings:

```
SELECT [type_desc]
      ,[name]
      ,[physical_name]
      ,[size]
      ,[max_size]
      ,[growth]
FROM [sys].[database_files];
```

There might be different solutions about your problem. For example, get more space and enable auto-grow option, execute the steps separately, etc.

Few things you check for sure:

- is your database under `FULL` or `SIMPLE` recovery model
- if it is using `FULL` recovery model, check if regular backups of the transaction log file are made (if such are not made, it will grow as many times as possible and eat your space)

If your database do not need to be under `FULL` recovery model, you can put it to `SIMPLE`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running these in the same query window, SSMS is running it all in one implicit transaction.  Try putting each of these in a seperate explicit transaction.  Also, clear your T-Log